# Laravel routing 404 error (Page not found)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have set up a controller for a sub folder in laravel 5 and I get a 404 error on the url /admin/home

AdminController.php - inside the controllers folder

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class AdminController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }


    public function home()
    {
        return view('admin.home');
    }

};
```

Route.php

```
Route::get('home' , 'AdminController@home');
```

home.php - inside views/Admin

```
@extends('admin')

@section('content')
<h1>Section admin home</h1>

@stop
```

Comment: did you try return view('Admin.home'); ?

Comment: Yep nothin still 404 , its on MAMP

Comment: how are you accessing the page? i mean what is the url on your url bar?

Comment: http://localhost:8888/laravel_test/admin/home thats what im using

Comment: remove the /admin part and see if it works... localhost:8888/laravel_test/home

Comment: The requested URL /laravel_test/home was not found on this server. its weird i kinda feel it should work

Comment: Did you created the controller using `php artisan make:controller` command? if not try after running `composer dump-autoload`. Then check you route shows on list that you get from `php artisan route:list`

Comment: I didnt no i made it by hand

Comment: for me it is working when i access it like http://localhost:8888/home

Comment: Please post your routes.php into there. Did you used Route::group ?Maybe problemis: 1. Your routes.php invalid. 2. Your fresh larvel work ? (http://localhost - apache/nginx config work properly?)

Comment: Looks like its a MAMP issue , ran php artisan serve and went to local host and now getting error NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

Answer (score 1):

Ok i dont see any probleme here except

```
Route::get('home' , 'AdminController@home');
```

so the link is not

```
exemple.dev/admin/home
```

But

```
exemple.dev/home
```

and also check **uppercase** and **lowercase** words (they must be the same if you are on linux)

```
return view('Admin.home'); // uppercase
```

Answer (score 0):

dont make the Route name 'home', this is use as an external command in php.... change it I thing it will work.

You can use,

```
Route::get('index' , 'AdminController@home');
Route::get('anyhing' , 'AdminController@home');
```

But dont use 'home' :)